# Alexa is not understanding few words

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I have developed a skill and everything is working smoothly except few words when asked to alexa. For example: If i am saying first, alexa is never getting first and log is saying that alexa heard frost, horst and many more word but first. Same goes for more, when I am saying more, alexa heard mor, mour,moire but more. These words are working good on mobile device but not on dot and spot. saying these word causing alexa to fire stopIntent.When i have fallbackIntent, then why it is firing StopIntent? Also i added mor in utterances but it doesn't pick up yet.

Comment: can you share your interaction model

Comment: can you confirm that your dot and spot devices are setup with the same language that you wrote your skill in?